# Python multi-threaded kubernetes watcher

Tags: python, multithreading

My program (which eventually will be containerised) should be able to do the following:

- continuously listening for deployment and daemonsets in kubernetes (2 threads)
- collect info needed (like annotations)
- use the info collected in order to create objects in a remote database

I could use some peer review for the thread part, which looks like this currently:

```
#first thread to watch for deployments
def watch_deployments():
    v1 = client.AppsV1Api()
    w = watch.Watch()
    last_seen_version = v1.list_deployment_for_all_namespaces().metadata.resource_version
    while True:
        for item in w.stream(v1.list_deployment_for_all_namespaces, pretty="pretty", resource_version=last_seen_version):
                _ = {item["object"].metadata.name:[item["object"].kind, item["object"].metadata.namespace, item["object"].metadata.resource_version, item["object"].metadata.annotations]}
                depl_lst.put(_)

def watch_daemonsets():
    v1 = client.AppsV1Api()
    w = watch.Watch()
    last_seen_version = v1.list_daemon_set_for_all_namespaces().metadata.resource_version
    while True:
        for item in w.stream(v1.list_daemon_set_for_all_namespaces, pretty="pretty", resource_version=last_seen_version):
            _ = {item["object"].metadata.name:[item["object"].kind, item["object"].metadata.namespace, item["object"].metadata.resource_version, item["object"].metadata.annotations]}
            depl_lst.put(_)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_obj = {}
    depl_lst = Queue()
    thread.start_new_thread(watch_deployments, ())
    thread.start_new_thread(watch_daemonsets, ())

    while True:
        for i in range(depl_lst.qsize()):
            current_obj = depl_lst.get()

            #add object is the function in order to create the item in the remote database, not listed here
            add_object()

            depl_lst.task_done()
```

Its the same thing with what is being done here but in this case, the asyncio was being used:
https://medium.com/@sebgoa/kubernets-async-watches-b8fa8a7ebfd4

Answer (score 1):

#### Restructuring and consolidation

*Dealing with API client instance*
Instead of generating a new `client.AppsV1Api` instance in each separate thread - create the instance in the main thread and pass *shared* API client to your threads constructors:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    v1 = client.AppsV1Api()
    thread.start_new_thread(watch_deployments, (v1,))
    thread.start_new_thread(watch_daemonsets, (v1))
    ...
```

---

Both target functions `watch_deployments` and `watch_daemonsets` perform essentially the same set of actions and differ only in specific **`v1.list_...`** routine.
To eliminate duplication the common behavior is extracted into a separate function say **`_gather_watched_metadata`** that will accept a particular `v1.list_...` function object as *callable*:

```
def _gather_watched_metadata(list_func):
    w = watch.Watch()
    last_seen_version = list_func().metadata.resource_version
    while True:
        for item in w.stream(list_func, pretty="pretty", resource_version=last_seen_version):
            metadata = item["object"].metadata
            _ = {metadata.name: [item["object"].kind, metadata.namespace,
                                 metadata.resource_version,
                                 metadata.annotations]}
            depl_lst.put(_)
```

As can be seen in the above function, to avoid repetitive indexing of nested attributes like `item["object"].metadata` it is worth to extract it into a variable at once.

Now, both target functions become just as below:

```
def watch_deployments(v1):
    _gather_watched_metadata(v1.list_deployment_for_all_namespaces)


def watch_daemonsets(v1):
    _gather_watched_metadata(v1.list_daemon_set_for_all_namespaces)
```

That can be shortened even further: both `watch_...` functions can be eliminated and you may run just with `_gather_watched_metadata` function and specific API routines passed as an argument :

```
...
v1 = client.AppsV1Api()
thread.start_new_thread(_gather_watched_metadata, (v1.list_deployment_for_all_namespaces,))
thread.start_new_thread(_gather_watched_metadata, (v1.list_daemon_set_for_all_namespaces,))
```

But to apply the last *"shortening"* - is up to you ...

---

*Consuming `depl_lst` queue*
Initiating `for` loop with `range` in this context:

```
while True:
    for i in range(depl_lst.qsize()):
        ...
```

is redundant as it's enough to check if queue is **not** [empty](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.empty):

```
while True:
    if not depl_lst.empty():
        current_obj = depl_lst.get()
```